# Firebase snapshot not being cast to dictionary

Tags: swift, dictionary, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this function that is supposed to fetch data from a `comments node` from firebase. I want to implement **pagination** to not load 100+ comments at once. Everything seems to be working but my code seems to be failing at casting the `snapchat.value` to a `Dictionary`

```
     func fetchComments(){
        messagesRef = Database.database().reference().child("Comments").child(eventKey)
        var query = messagesRef?.queryOrderedByKey()
        if comments.count > 0 {
           let value =  comments.last?.commentID
            query = query?.queryStarting(atValue: value)
        }
        query?.queryLimited(toFirst: 2).observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

            var allObjects = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot]

            allObjects?.forEach({ (snapshot) in
                 // print out snapshot and it isn't empty 
                print(snapshot.value) // here it keeps going into the else statement even though snapshot.value clearly exist.

                guard let commentDictionary = snapshot.value as? [String:Any] else{
                    return
                }

                print(commentDictionary)
            })
                   }) { (err) in
            print("Failed to observe comments")
        }
    }
```

My question is can anyone take a look at this and maybe see where I went wrong? My code looks fine to me and I can't see what's is wrong.

My tree looks like this

```
"Comments" : {
"CCDS" : {
  "-KrrsXkj6FznzRD0-Xzs" : {
    "content" : "Shawn",
    "profileImageURL" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/eventful-3d558.appspot.com/o/profile_images%2FBC868F8F-E9EC-4B9D-A248-DD2187BC140C.PNG?alt=media&token=fb14700c-2b05-4077-b45c-afd3de705801",
    "timestamp" : 1.503102381340935E9,
    "uid" : "oxgjbrhingbf7vbaHpflhw6G7tB2"
  }
},
"MIA" : {
  "-Krghz9d5_CPjkmdffef" : {
    "content" : "22",
    "profileImageURL" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/eventful-3d558.appspot.com/o/profile_images%2FF50F6915-DEAB-4A5B-B1AB-CABC1E349148.PNG?alt=media&token=4eb7c708-ec87-45bf-952d-0bd410faee50",
    "timestamp" : 1.502915064803007E9,
    "uid" : "oxgjbrhingbf7vbaHpflhw6G7tB2"
  },
  "-KrpoEnNYsmRZ5guORUj" : {
    "content" : "23",
    "profileImageURL" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/eventful-3d558.appspot.com/o/profile_images%2FBC868F8F-E9EC-4B9D-A248-DD2187BC140C.PNG?alt=media&token=fb14700c-2b05-4077-b45c-afd3de705801",
    "timestamp" : 1.503067700479352E9,
    "uid" : "oxgjbrhingbf7vbaHpflhw6G7tB2"
  }
}
  }
```

Based off my code it bypasses the key and goes straight to the children.
For example if pass in MIA it should go to MIA and grab the key corresponding to each comment  "-KrrsXkj6FznzRD0-Xzs" and  "-KrpoEnNYsmRZ5guORUj" but it is returning everything under that unique ID instead. Which is a problem

Comment: I think your issue is that you have the `snapshot` variable on repeat, I would change the name name in `allObjects?.forEach({ (snapshot) ` to something like `eachObj. So you might not know which one you are printing out

Comment: okay i will try that

Comment: seems to be working but that's weird I don't get how that would effect it

Comment: it is working or seems to be working?

Comment: well it is not hitting the return statement so I guess it is being assigned.

Comment: but why would that effect the answer

Comment: no now it is adding too many messages

Comment: yeah it definitely is not working @Lamar

Comment: I believe the logic you apply in the code is not working, I point out that you were using the wrong snapshot variable, because it seems that you were trying to cast `[DataSnaphot]` to `[String:Any]`, you would need to provide much detail into what you are trying to achieve for us to help you now

Comment: Im just trying to print out the key for each comment in my database for some reason it isnt printing it out right it is printing out everything under the comment1 node

Comment: Im just trying to print out the key for each comment in my database for some reason it isnt printing it out right it is printing out everything under the comment1 node

Comment: like for some reason its going down one level too much

Comment: your response are too vague, elaborate on what is really going on, give example ?

Comment: @Lamar see edits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in your callback seems to assume that you get called with a collection of comments. To get such a collection you need to observe the `.value` event. When you observe the `.value` event, you callback gets invoked with a single `snapshot` that contains all the nodes matching the query:

```
   query?.queryLimited(toFirst: 2).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

        var allObjects = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot]

        allObjects?.forEach({ (snapshot) in
            print(snapshot.key)
            print(snapshot.value)

            guard let commentDictionary = snapshot.value as? [String:Any] else{
                return
            }

            print(commentDictionary)
        })
    }) { (err) in
        print("Failed to observe comments")
    }
```

When you observe `.childAdded`, your callback instead gets called for every individual node matching the query. That means you need to get rid of a loop in your code:

```
   query?.queryLimited(toFirst: 2).observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
        print(snapshot.key)
        print(snapshot.value)

        guard let commentDictionary = snapshot.value as? [String:Any] else{
            return
        }

        print(commentDictionary)

    }) { (err) in
        print("Failed to observe comments")
    }
```

Comment: which one of these will allow for realtime update of comments?

Comment: One side question though. You know how when you search for something on instagram the results of user's found seemingly pop up in real time. Is there any way to do that without adding all results from firebase to an array and querying

Comment: I need your help